# CSS left is not working correctly in Internet Explorer

Tags: css

```
#tab {
    position: relative;
    float:right;
    height: 22px;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
       -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
         -o-transform-origin: 0 0;
            transform-origin: 0 0;
            -ms-transform-origin:0 50px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(+90deg) translate(0px, 0px);
        -ms-transform: rotate(+90deg);
       -moz-transform: rotate(+90deg) translate(0px, 0px);
         -o-transform: rotate(+90deg) translate(0px, 0px);
            transform: rotate(+90deg);        /* IE10 */
    text-decoration:none;
    list-style-type:none;
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    z-index:100;   
    left:110px;
    top:-5px;
    text-shadow:none;
}
```

Here the left property which is left:110px; is working correct in Google Chrome and Moz Firefox, however, it is not working correctly in IE 11, what I need to do is for Internet Explorer it must be left:59px;, So how can I fix this problem, I tried conditional html classes but I realized that It is not supporting anymore after IE 10

Comment: Why you need such difference for IE? The way isn't be the same on every browser?

Comment: relative position with right float with left and top specified. something doesn't feel right!

Comment: any reason you're using a 50px transform-origin for IE? That'll affect the rotation.

Comment: My question right after reading your question is: what is really your question? I mean, what are you trying to do?

Comment: take out that float:right and treat IE as an equal to Webkit (dont translate 0,50px in ms but not in webkit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is "50px transform-origin for IE"
I just removed this line and it works same in 3 browsers